# Coq - dependent type error in rewrite

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I am using the Mathematical Components library and I am trying to prove this:

```
Lemma card_sub_ord (k : nat) (P : nat -> bool) :
  #|[set i : 'I_k | P i]| <= k.
Proof.
  set S := [set i : 'I_k | P i].
  have H1 : S \subset 'I_k.
    by apply: subset_predT.
  have H2 : #|S| <= #|'I_k|.
    by apply: subset_leq_card.
  have H3 : k = #|'I_k|.
    by rewrite card_ord.
  (* Only goal left: #|S| <= k *)
  rewrite H3 (* <--- this fails *)
Admitted.
```

The last rewrite fails with an error message:

> Error: dependent type error in rewrite of `(fun _pattern_value_ : nat => is_true (#|S| <= _pattern_value_)`

Any idea on why the rewrite fails or an explanation of this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your rewrite fails is that `k` appears as a hidden parameter in `S`, thus by rewriting all the occurrences you make the goal ill-typed. You can check this by using `Set Printing All`.

```
by rewrite {5}H3.
```

will close your goal. Note that naming goals in `H1...Hn` style is not encouraged in mathcomp. Your indentation also doesn't follow math-comp style, and you may want to use `exact:` in place of `by apply:`.

Your proof can also be made shorter by using `max_card`:

```
by rewrite -{8}(card_ord k) max_card.
```

or

```
by rewrite -[k in _ <= k]card_ord max_card.
```

thou you could also prefer to use a more generic from that won't require specifying the indexes:

```
suff: #|[set i : 'I_k | P i]| <= #|'I_k| by rewrite card_ord.
exact: max_card.
```

Another way to avoid index tinkering is to rely on transitivity:

```
by rewrite (leq_trans (max_card _)) ?card_ord.
```

YMMV.